# mysql update query does not work with different column

Tags: mysql

After spending few hours searching for the solution on stack I can't seem to get the right answer on this one.

I have 2 tables: "repairs" & "relation"
In the table "repairs" there are 4 columns named "repair_external_supplierID", "relation_id", "cliendID" and "supplierID". (besides the ID column)
In the table "relation" I have 2 columns named "sRelationNumber" & "sCustomerNumber". (besides the ID column)
The "supplierID" in "repairs" is empty and needs to be filled with the data from column "ID" from "Relation" where the "repair_external_supplierID" from "repairs" matches the "sRelationNumber" from "relation"
the same thing goes for "clientID" in "repairs, which has to be filled in when the column "relation_id" from "repairs" matches the column "sCustomerNumber" from "relation"

this is the code :

```
/*--SET SUPPLIER ID --*/
UPDATE repairs
SET supplierID = (
SELECT
    id
FROM
    relation
WHERE
    relation.sRelationNumber = repairs.repair_external_supplierID
)
 WHERE
supplierID = '' OR supplierID IS NULL;

/*--SET CLIENT ID --*/
UPDATE repairs
SET clientID = (
SELECT
    id
FROM
    relation
WHERE
     relation.sCustomerNumber = repairs.relation_id
)
WHERE
clientID = '' OR clientID IS NULL;
```

For some reasone the first query works as planned, the second one is returning "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Why is that?

Comment: It's self-explanatory - it even tells you that subquery returns more than one row. Let's see what you're after - you want to update `clientID` value with a number. You issue a subquery. Subquery finds more than 1 row that satisfies the condition, and that value can't fit in the `clientID`. Your first query doesn't yield more than 1 row so it's fine. What you need to do is sit down and deduce logic behind this.

Comment: Because `relation.sCustomerNumber = repairs.relation_id` returns more than one row.

Comment: but "relation.sRelationNumber = repairs.repair_external_supplierID" returns also more than one row... that's why I can't seem to find the problem :(

Comment: update : I know that this should be a walk in the park, but maybe i'm looking to far to fix this. I only want the query to grab the matching "id" from relations if the value of sCustomerNumber = relation_id. And then put it in the column clientID.

Comment: Are you sure you want your `clientID` to be set to `relation.id`? It doesn't look right. Does the `relation` table contain some sort of `sCustomerID` or something similar? It appears that there are multiple records in `relation` table for a single `repairs.relation_id`, that's the core of the problem. You can always add `LIMIT 1` in your subquery, but then the question is - will that be what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

this is the content of my tables

```
RELATION
id       sCustomerNumber     sSupplierNumber        sRelationNumber
1        K12345              S456789                R123456
2        K98765              S456678                R987654
3        K15789              S957876                R854754
....
```

None of these rows have the same numbers
This is what my REPAIRS table looks like :

```
REPAIRS
id      clientID       relation_id      supplierID    external_supplier_id
1                      K12345                         R123456
2                      K98765                         R987654           
3                      K15789                         R854754
```

and this should become:

```
REPAIRS
id      clientID       relation_id      supplierID    external_supplier_id
1       1              K12345           1             R123456
2       2              K98765           2             R987654           
3       3              K15789           3             R854754
```

Comment: OK, found the problem, feeling mighty stupid. here's what happened.
The table "repairs" contained some rows which had nothing for relation_id.
This caused the error "more than 1 row". so, I just needed to exclude these ones by adding   "AND (relation.sCustomerNumber <> '')" inside the subquery... problem solved!